# How run GraphDB as a Windows Service

Tags: graphdb

I would like to run GaphDB in Windows as a service to hide the log events and makes sure it will start automatically when the server is restarted.

What is the best/easy way to start GraphDB as a Service?

Tks

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a service out of it using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) which has a bunch of options when setting up the service.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to register GraphDB as windows service (as mentioned above) is :

1. Download the latest release of NSSM - http://nssm.cc/download .
2. Unzip it .
3. Open command prompt ( right click cmd - run as administrator).
4. Go to nssm's folder ( e.g. C:\Users\onto\Downloads\nssm-2.24\nssm-2.24\win64 ).
5. Run nssm install your_desired_service_name . This will open GUI, when you are able to point to graphdb.cmd file .

Now you are able to control graphdb through windows service console .